# How to create a scheduler task in Window Task Scheduler using Java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a task under Window Task Scheduler using my java code.
OS I am using is win7 64bit.
After creating the task I have to edit the scheduled time weekly or biweekly.
Is there any window scheduler API to use in java code or command to use under command prompt?

Comment: Google always knock the stackoverflow door before whispering. :)

Answer (score 4):

Launch the command line utility [schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx).

To create the task.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestWinScheduler {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  // schtasks /create /tn "HowToTask" /tr c:\temp\test.cmd /sc once /st 00:00:00 /sd 2022/01/01 /ru username /rp password

  List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();

  commands.add("schtasks.exe");
  commands.add("/CREATE");
  commands.add("/TN");
  commands.add("\"HowToTask\"");
  commands.add("/TR");
  commands.add("\"c:/temp/test.cmd\"");
  commands.add("/SC");
  commands.add("once");
  commands.add("/ST");
  commands.add("00:00:00");
  commands.add("/SD");
  commands.add("2022/10/10");
  commands.add("/RU");
  commands.add("username");
  commands.add("/RP");
  commands.add("password");

  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
  Process p = builder.start();
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println(p.exitValue()); // 0 : OK
                                     // 1 : Error
  }
}
```

To execute a task :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestWinScheduler {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  // schtasks /run /tn "HowToTask"

  List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();

  commands.add("schtasks.exe");
  commands.add("/RUN");
  commands.add("/TN");
  commands.add("\"HowtoTask\"");

  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
  Process p = builder.start();
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println(p.exitValue()); // 0 : OK
                                     // 1 : Error
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code working file for me. But when I delete scheduler task using my code it says **ERROR: Access is denied.** and it get deleted when I do it manually in Window Task Scheduler. Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Windows have already a task scheduler that you can invoke from command line: Schtasks.exe

SCHTASKS /parameter [arguments]

Description:
    Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and
    end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system.

Parameter List:
/Create         Creates a new scheduled task.

/Delete         Deletes the scheduled task(s).

/Query          Displays all scheduled tasks.

/Change         Changes the properties of scheduled task.

/Run            Runs the scheduled task on demand.

/End            Stops the currently running scheduled task.

/ShowSid        Shows the security identifier corresponding to a scheduled t
ask name.

/?              Displays this help message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/. Using "YAJSW" (Yet Another Java Service Wrapper) you can register your java service as a windows service.