# Use Java program to trigger a Windows Task Scheduler task

Tags: java, windows, taskscheduler

I'm making a home automation system in Java, and I'd like to have a program running on my computer that can take inputs from connected modules around the house and trigger tasks on my PC using Task Scheduler (like opening different apps or executing separate java programs). Is there a way to make a Java program trigger these tasks, or should I look for another tool to do this?

Comment: Did you have a chance to take a look at the Java's [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) API?

Comment: The Task Scheduler provides many triggers, all of them are system-provided. It does not offer an interface to introduce custom triggers. You are looking at the wrong tool to solve your problem. The solution is probably something along the lines of a configuration file.

Comment: Thank you both. I didn't know about Timers before, but it'll probably be easier to use them than what I was envisioning. I can probably whip up a TimerFactory or some such custom class that can build them from a configuration file to make them easier to update. I didn't think about it before, but using Timers will make it easier to make my program cross-platform and faster to set up on new systems.

Comment: Timers, too, are the wrong tool. You want to respond to events. The canonical solution to that is to set up listeners, and connect them to the respective event sources. How to do that in detail depends on the event sources, and the framework in use.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to create a scheduler task in Window Task Scheduler using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39745154/3744182).